# event_data('plotly_relayout') changes to initial values after resize of browser window

Tags: shiny-server, r-plotly, shiny-reactivity

I have a Dashboard in Shiny using basically the `shinydashboard` library. The first Panel deals with the analysis of temporal data, with a lot of variables over time. So I use an initial plot, made with `plotly` and use the `rangeslider` to select specific time intervals. Then I want to use the timestamps created by the sliders as limits for further analysis with other variables but in the same time interval which was selected in the first plot.

To achieve that I use `event_data('plotly_relayout')` pointing to the source plot.

Now what happens is that, once I select the slider positions, the dates are set and used in the follow up plots. But if the browser window scale changes, those values are reset to some initial values of the slider which are 'width' and `height`.

I have tried every possible conditions to work around this problem but in the end I can't find a solution to avoid the reset of the values when resizing the browser window. I tried other sources of event_data(), like `plotly_click`,
  `plotly_doubleclick`, `plotly_selected` and it all works fine. Only not with the sliders and `plotly_relayout`.

If you run the code below, have a look at the variables `xmin` and `xmax` after closing the app. There are the cases:

(I) Starting app -> do nothing -> close window -> variables stay empty (thats fine)

(II) Starting app -> resize window -> close window -> variables have values of `width` and `height`

(III) Starting app -> change sliders -> close window -> variables have values of the dates

(IV) Starting app -> change sliders -> resize window -> close window -> variables have initial values of `width` and `height`

```
if (interactive()) {
   library(shiny)
   library(plotly)
   # Download some data
   getSymbols(Symbols = 'AAPL')

   ds <- data.frame(Date = index(AAPL), AAPL[,6])

   ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput('plot'))

   server <- function(input, output, session) {

      output$plot <- renderPlotly({
         plot_ly(ds, x = ~Date, y = ~AAPL.Adjusted, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines + markers', name = 'Some Name', source = 'timeline_plot') %>% 
            layout(
               title = 'Stock Prices',
               xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = 'date')),
               yaxis = list(title = 'Price'))
      })

      observeEvent(event_data('plotly_relayout', source = 'timeline_plot'), {
         event.data <<- event_data('plotly_relayout', source = 'timeline_plot')

         if(is.null(event.data[['xaxis.range']]) == TRUE){
            xmin <<- event.data[[1]]
            xmax <<- event.data[[2]]
         }else{
            xmin <<- event.data[['xaxis.range']][1]
            xmax <<- event.data[['xaxis.range']][2]
         }
      })
   }

   shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

Assuming I declare event.data <- `event_data('plotly_relayout')` like in the code above, then the initial values when I resize the window are, `event.data$witdth` and `event.data$height` which are the values of the slider in some unit and represented as integer.

Once I use the slider to set the date range, then those values change into a list with two values, `event.data[['xaxis.range']][1]` and `event.data[['xaxis.range']][2]`. The class of this values changes to character.

The class does not matter in this case, since I can handle those things in the follow up plots.

But what happens now, is that once selected the slider values and I resize the panel size where the plots are, by resizing the browser window or by simply using a sidebar with `shinydashboard`, or use other elements from `shinyWidgets` package that resize the initial plot. The `event.data` values change to the initial values, `width` and `height` and thus reset the other plots.